# c# web browser control in STA thread consume high volume of usage

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i am trying to simulate a web browser in the c# code, since the url have the javascript, i am intend to wait him like 100 miliseconds to grab the full content from it, in the end, we cannot use method like web client to direct download from it, so i am trying to use web browser to take the content, the following is my code:

```
  var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT top 200 stock_code FROM update_stock_code", connection);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);


                cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM update_stock_code where stock_code in (select TOP 200 * FROM update_stock_code)", connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
                {
                    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
                    wb.DocumentCompleted += Wb_DocumentCompleted;
                    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                    wb.Tag = dt.Rows[a][0].ToString();
                    wb.Navigate("URL");


                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
                }
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();

                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(300000);
                }
            }
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();


private static void Wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
            string content = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
            long milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                long milliseconds2 = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
                if (milliseconds2 - milliseconds > 100)
                {
                    //some code event
                    break;
                }
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            }
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread();
            wb.Dispose();
            /* ... */
        }
```

However, when i am using the above code, it was taking me like 33% usage of my processor and i am trying to open 2 program of this and it hit 100% of my CPU, may i ask how to reduce the CPU usage before it burned my processor? Am i doing anything wrong on the code?

Comment: Why are you calling Application.Run() in a loop?

Comment: @LaneL i tried, if dont use this it will not run the document completed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread